# Binary Masks and Bits manipulation in C

Tags: c, string, binary, bit, masking

I've got a task and i have no clue what i supposed to do. Here is the task:

Write the following function:
char * encodingToShortString (char * dig_str);

The function is supposed to create and return a new string **short_dig_str**.
Each byte in **short_dig_str** will consist of the two corresponding bit quartets for two consecutive characters of **dig_str**.
For **dig_str** with the length n (LENGTH, not size), the length of **short_dig_str** would be n / 2 for even n and n / 2 + 1 for odd n.
For odd n, the first quartet in **short_dig_str** does not match any digit of **dig_str** and all its bits are zeros.

Example:
For **dig_str** = "1234", the string **short_dig_str** will consist of the following integer:
00010010 00110100

For **dig_str** = "51234", the string **short_dig_str** will consist of the following integer:
00000101 00010010 00110100

(From left to right, the most significant, MSB, to the least significant LSB).

The required memory space must be assigned to the **short_dig_str** string accurately.
It can be assumed that there is enough memory for allocation.

I've started the function like this:

```
char* codingToShortString(char* dig_str)//let's imagine that dig_str[] = "12";
{
   char *short_dig_str;
   char temp;//0000 0000
   int n = strlen(dig_str);
   unsigned mask = 1<<3;//1111
   unsigned c; //bit counter
   if (n%2 == 0)
   {
     short_dig_str = malloc(((n/2)+1)*sizeof(char));
   }
   else
   {
     short_dig_str = malloc(((n/2)+2)*sizeof(char));
   }
   for (i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
     for (c=1; c<=4; c++)
      {
        temp = dig_str[i] & mask;
        temp <<= 1;
      }
   }
}
```

But afterwards i have no clue what to do. How i put the binary value into **short_dig_str**? I'm very confused.

Comment: What you are expected to do is called "BCD encoding". You may think about it like converting "1234" into {0x12, 0x34}. You do not need to go the way via bitmasks.

Comment: `mask` is not `0x1111`: `unsigned mask = 1<<3;//1111`

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. Please revise it and edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look at the desired output:

> Example: For dig_str = "1234", the string short_dig_str will consist of the following integer: 00010010 00110100
>
> For dig_str = "51234", the string short_dig_str will consist of the following integer: 00000101 00010010 00110100

With "integer" a (unsigned) char is meant. If you write the result as hex values you will get

> "1234"  => 0x12, 0x34
>
> "51234" => 0x05, 0x12, 0x34

You are following an approach that is too complicated.
You do not need any bitmasks for this.

```
char* codingToShortString(char* dig_str)
{
  int n = strlen(dig_str);

  // Add 1 before dividing to "round up", add 1 for \0
  char *short_dig_str = malloc((n+1)/2 + 1);

  unsigned char digits;
  int out_pos = 0;  // Read index within input: "12345"
  int in_pos = 0;   // Write index within output: {0x01,0x23,0x34}

  // First handle odd number of digits
  // Foe even numbers no special treatment needed.
  if (n%2 != 0)
  {
    digits = dig_str[in_pos++] - '0';
    short_dig_str[out_pos++] = digit;
  }

  // Then handle remaining digits (as pairs!).
  for ( ; in_pos < n; )
  {
      digits  = (dig_str[in_pos++] -'0') << 4; // one digits in upper half ...
      digits |= dig_str[in_pos++] - '0';       // ... one digit in lower half

      // Store into result array...
      short_dig_str[out_pos++] = digits;
  }

  return short_dig_str;
}
```

As the returned pointer is not used as a string but as raw bytes to store 2 decimals, it should be `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` etc. rather than `char` but your signature is defined as it is.

The name `codingToShortString` is misleading, as no string (and no 0-termination) is created.

Bad names, bad types... That's not a really good assignment I would say...

Comment: i don't understand your code, can you please explain in more details?

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. But for some reason if i want to print the new string, it doesnt print anything. More interesting: if i set the length of the source string as 2 and the string "12", there is no output, but if i set the length 4 and the string "1234", it prints 4, that is wrong. Why? I've tried to modify the main function several times, no changes.

Comment: Did you read that I mentioned that the output is not a string? If yes, what/how do you try to print? Extra hint: what ist the ASCII value of '4'?

Comment: Thanks a lot, ive handled this one and 2 more exercises in bitwise operations.